# How to change interface of eCommerce platform Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have a question.
please tell me , how to change interface of Hybris

I wanna enlarge the results this class is "olcResultList"
the class change 120 to 600pix

Comment: Please elaborate your question..

Comment: Are you using the accelerator ? If yes what store ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find your class incss files under   ${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR} /ext-template/yacceleratorstorefront/web/webroot/_ui/   [read this  for more info](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=hybris%20certification%20questions)